# Why does HttpClient throw an exception when the request is successful?

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, akamai

I'm using `HttpClient` in the context of a web request to send another web request as follows:

```
private async Task SendManagerInfoAsync(Uri baseUri, string accessToken, object obj,
    string apiPath, HttpMethod httpMethod)
{
    string authToken = await GetManagerAuthToken(baseUri, accessToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    string url = new Uri(baseUri, apiPath).AbsoluteUri;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, url)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))
    };
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);

    // For whatever reason, always throws a TaskCanceledException.
    var response = await m_httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

The request I'm tracking down is an HTTP PUT. For some reason, this code always throws a `TaskCanceledException` once it reaches the preset `HttpClient.Timeout` length, about 30 seconds. However, when I check the recipient of this request, I see that the datastore is *always* already updated with the information I'd sent *within one second of the originating request*.

I don't understand why or how the `HttpClient` instance would throw an exception when the request is actually successful. No cancellation token is being requested. Has anyone ever seen a behavior like this before?

---

<sup>* I tagged this question as related to Akamai because I can only observe this behavior when we flip a switch turning on Akamai services for the server receiving the request.</sup>

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually getting a response.  What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: @SLaks I'm getting [an HTTP 500 response](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/13120/847201/iX43j40gUsI5WDk/upload.png) which includes the stack trace of the `TaskCanceledException`.

Comment: Clearly an Unhanded exception occurring on the web server - and you have not shown us the web server code.  I think this has gone as far as it can for the moment.

Comment: @SamAxe what's interesting about this situation is that when the Akamai switch is off, there's no exception. Moreover, the server has a fairly robust error logging service, and we can verify that no errors are logged when the client receives the task canceled exception.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the prodding to do some more investigation via Fiddler; this got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up inspecting the apparently unsuccessful request sent by `HttpClient` and a successful request sent by Chrome Postman. `HttpClient` by default includes the `Expect: 100-continue` header in each request. I disabled it as follows, and the request started behaving normally again.

```
m_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

(I don't have a good answer as to *why* this works, but it's gotten me moving forward again for the moment.)

---

*Edit*: It appears that it works this way because Akamai strictly interprets [RFC 2616 8.2.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3), which declares an origin server, if it receives a request with the `Expect: 100-continue` header,

- > MUST either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read from the input stream, or respond with a final status code
- > MUST NOT perform the requested method if it returns a final status code

So Akamai is still waiting for the 100 response code, which it never gets, so the request times out, which translates to the `TaskCanceledException` thrown by the `HttpClient`.

I still don't know why `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue` *defaults* to `true` rather than `false`, but that's a question for another day.

Comment: Some servers don't correctly handle the expect header.  The twitter API used to be one of these.  The Expect header is designed to allow a server to refuse an oversized request payload.  Turning off expect header will do no harm if the server doesn't support it and will in fact increase performance by reducing a round trip.